# How to formulate the line segment drawn from the left vertex point of the ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections, angle, fixed-points

**Polar form relative to center**

In polar coordinates, with the origin at the center of the ellipse and with the angular coordinate $\theta$ measured from the major axis, the ellipse's equation is

$r(\theta)=\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{1-(e\cos\theta)^2}}$

[image: an ellipse with the angle and distance marked from the center to an arbitrary point]

**Polar form relative to focus**

If instead we use polar coordinates with the origin at one focus, with the angular coordinate $\theta = 0$ still measured from the major axis, the ellipse's equation is

$r(\theta)=\dfrac{a(1-e^2)}{1\pm e\cos\theta}$

[image: an ellipse with the angle and distance marked from one focus to an arbitrary point]

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse

But I couldn't find **polar form relative to vertex**. What is the formula that provides the relationship between $\theta$ angle and $r$ length? $0 \leq \theta < \pi/2$
[image: an ellipse with the angle and distance marked from one major vertix to an arbitrary point]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Begin with the cartesian equation of an ellipse with the vertex on the origin:

$$\frac{(x-a)^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Substitute $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$ and solve for $r$ to get

$$r = \frac{2ab^2\cos\theta}{b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta}$$